# Parsing a file after upload in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nokogiri

I want to be able to upload an xml file to my rails app and have it then parse through the file and generate ActiveRecord entries based off the contents.

I've put together a parser using nokogiri that works fine in vanilla Ruby, so no problem there, but for some reason Rails seems to want to run through it before I've even hit the upload button to supply it with the file. As soon as I try to go to the upload page, I receive this

```
TypeError in FoobarsController#create
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

what I've got looks like this:

app/models/foobar.rb

```
class Foobar < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :xml_file
  has_attached_file :xml_file
  before_save :parse_file

  def parse_file
    require 'xml_parser'
    myFile = xml_file.queued_for_write[:original]
    fooParser = Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(FoobarParser.new)
    fooParser.parse(File.open(myFile,mode='r'))
  end
end
```

app/controllers/foobars_controller.rb

```
class FoobarsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @foobar = Foobar.new
  end
  def create
    @foobar = Foobar.new(params[:foobar])
    if @foobar.save
      redirect_to @foobar
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/foobars/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Upload foobar</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3 center">
        <%= form_for(@foobar) do |f| %>
            <%= f.file_field :xml_file %>
            <%= f.submit %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I guess it's a problem with the controller's create method, but I was basing my code on [this](http://larsgebhardt.de/parse-xml-with-ruby-on-rails-paperclip-and-nokogiri/) so I thought it should do what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace & line number of that error message?

Comment: Did you try this: `<%= form_for (@foobar), multipart: true do %>` that's what I do with uploading a CSV file

Comment: @BenScheirman - it's coming from the line `fooParser.parse(File.open(myFile,mode='r'))` - the error's basically just saying that it's trying to parse a blank file, because it's trying to parse something before even bringing you to the upload page, so there's nothing for it to parse.

@MohamedElMahallawy - It produces the same error that way. I'm fairly sure that what's happening is that it's trying to do `@foobar.save` as soon as the page loads rather than when you've uploaded the file like I'd want it to.

Comment: This question is too broad. Perhaps you should split it into two questions: one about how to upload a file, and the second about parsing the XML.

Comment: @user2958498 please edit your question and post the entire stack track & line number of error message.